# cannot access Tomcat7 admin interface

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7

I am trying to access the admin interface of tomcat7 on my machine without success.Here is the tomcat-users.xml file for the username and roles.

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
```

My system runs Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 9):

Because ubuntu has separated tomcat in different pkgs.

If you only exec `apt-get install tomcat7`,that means you just install the core pkg.

If you want to manage tomcat, that means you have to exec `apt-get install tomcat7-admin`.

And maybe you want to install many other tomcat7 pkgs, you can `apt-get install tomcat7<tab><tab>`, it will list other tomcat7 pkgs.

**It's not over yet.** Tomcat's webapps dir is default at `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/`.

After you install `tomcat7-admin`, you have to copy the dir to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/` by using this command:

`cp -r /usr/share/tomcat7-admin/* /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/`

And you can find other tomcat7.* pkgs are all expand to `/usr/share/${pkg_name}/` dir. Just copy them to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/`. It will works.

Comment: @mungaihkamau So at this time. Let me know the result of ``ls -l /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps``, and why you can't access admin page. Any errors?

Comment: @mungaihkamau I think the result is that you forgot to restart tomcat to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file is not well-formed.
There is a closing `tomcat-users`tag missing. Try adding this line to your `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: The tag is there,i left it out by mistake when writing the question.